# An account accessible via mutilple emails

Tags: support, login, user-accounts, email

First I signed up an account with Facebook by the email **foo@email.com**
Then I signed up another account with Google by the email **bar@email.com**
Then I go to Facebook and change my primary email to **bar@email.com**
Login with Facebook again and now I see that the 2 accounts merged together

Total time spent added together, questions and answers also merged. However some badges are missing (**Vox Populi**, **Suffrage** and **Educated**)
Now I can log in to this account by both email

Is this behavior considered normal?
Edit:
Badges are coming back, just not instantly when 2 accounts merged (Seem like they are awarded on scheduled processes)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You had an account registered using **foo@gmail.com** as a Google credential, and another account registered using **bar@gmail.com** as a Facebook credential. At some point, you changed your email address on Facebook because when you tried logging in via Facebook, we recognized the same Facebook ID, but we saw that the email was now **foo@gmail.com**. So the bar account you had needed to add this new verified foo email to the account, but it was already connected to another account via your Google credential. Thus, the system recognized two accounts which had both *verified* the same email address and merged them together automatically. This is very much by design.

Simply changing your email address in your profile will never trigger such an automatic merge because you can type anything you want there - it's not verified and we don't know that's actually your email. On the other hand, if you typed it into your preferences as your notification email *and* went on to verify it by email, then that would result in two accounts with the same verified email and trigger an auto-merge. Changing it in your profile *does* drop your account into a queue for manual review if it matches a verified email on another account - and we may end up merging them manually if we can easily verify that both accounts belong to the same user.

We have no implicit limit on the number of credentials you can have attached to a single account (I have eight connected to mine), and you can use any one of them to login to your account in the future. You can view the ones attached to your account as well as add new ones and delete old ones by visiting the My Logins link in the side-menu while editing your profile.

As for the badges: depending on which way your accounts were merged, you'll lose all the badges from one of the accounts. If you still qualify to receive them, they'll be automatically re-awarded to you the next time each relevant badge process runs. If you don't (possibly because the post is now deleted) then the badge is simply lost forever - there's nothing we can do about it.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, can you elaborate more on what specific conditions where you badges are kept/lost